# NSURLErrorDomain when retrieving large JSON dataset from restful WCF

Tags: ios, wcf, rest, nsurlrequest

I have a very wierd problem.
I expose a Restfull webservice using WCF. I consume it succesfulle using an Android app i have made.
I'm no making a simular IOS app, that should use the same REST methods.

I have tried both AFNetworking and MKNetworkKit, to check i the error i have is related to the API.

The problem:
The webservice provides a POST method that sometimes returns large amounts of data, other times small amount.
Posting to the service for a JSON dataset with a fairly small amont of data works like a charm.
Posting to the service for a JSON set with a large amount of data will immediately throw this error:

> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

The methodcall is excatly the same both on the IOS device and the serverside. It is just a matter of how much data is in the JSON.

I can debug the serverside and see that it returns the dataset, and just at the moment the data is returned the IOS device throws the exception.

I have only tested in the simulator, and there is WIFI all the time.

It works fine on my android app. It works fine using Fiddler 2 to post the call. Only IOS fails.

I think the problem lies on the IOS side, but i cannot pinpoint where.

I hope someone has some inspiring input.

Regards
PS: IOS 5